# Customization of URL's of theme post types

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, customization, custom-post-type

We are trying to setup a new url structure for themes custom post type called Tour Item. We want to rename that in url to say example "Property"
http://gotravel.mikado-themes.com/tour-item/gaudis-city/
here is the url structure so you get the idea.. 
so we would like for it to be http://gotravel.mikado-themes.com/property/gaudis-city/ - for example.

Also we would like to add categories into url structure, example
www.travel.com/greece/santorini/property/name-of-property.

One tiny problem is that this theme adds custom post types with plugin, and we would like to avoid editing plugins because of future updates. Is there some function that I can add to edit a custom post type added by plugin.
I tried several ones but none of them works unfortunately.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have changed once the plugin custom post type as you have described above. I also faced the same issue but i solved with this code.

```
add_action('registered_post_type', 'rename_custom_post_type_name', 10, 2);
function rename_custom_post_type_name($post_type, $args) {
global $wp_rewrite;
if ($post_type == 'tour-item') { //your old slug here
    $args->rewrite['slug'] = 'property'; //write your new slug here
    if ( $args->has_archive ) {
            $archive_slug = $args->has_archive === true ? $args->rewrite['slug'] : $args->has_archive;
            if ( $args->rewrite['with_front'] )
                    $archive_slug = substr( $wp_rewrite->front, 1 ) . $archive_slug;
            else
                    $archive_slug = $wp_rewrite->root . $archive_slug;
            add_rewrite_rule( "{$archive_slug}/?$", "index.php?post_type=$post_type", 'top' );
            if ( $args->rewrite['feeds'] && $wp_rewrite->feeds ) {
                    $feeds = '(' . trim( implode( '|', $wp_rewrite->feeds ) ) . ')';
                    add_rewrite_rule( "{$archive_slug}/feed/$feeds/?$", "index.php?post_type=$post_type" . '&feed=$matches[1]', 'top' );
                    add_rewrite_rule( "{$archive_slug}/$feeds/?$", "index.php?post_type=$post_type" . '&feed=$matches[1]', 'top' );
            }
            if ( $args->rewrite['pages'] )
                    add_rewrite_rule( "{$archive_slug}/{$wp_rewrite->pagination_base}/([0-9]{1,})/?$", "index.php?post_type=$post_type" . '&paged=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    }
    $permastruct_args = $args->rewrite;
    $permastruct_args['feed'] = $permastruct_args['feeds'];
    add_permastruct( $post_type, "{$args->rewrite['slug']}/%$post_type%", $permastruct_args );
}
}
```

Since, you are trying to update the post url, it has to be changed in lot of places.

Another problem of yours which is you want your category to work which i will not able to help you right now.

Hope this works for you to change url to new one.

Thanks